# Bad allocation importing MDF file

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to import a (Inca) MDF file by using read function

```
linkData = mdf(fileName);
rawDat = read(linkData);
```

however the following comes out

[image]

Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: Without some example data it's pretty hard to diagnose why _some file_ which we can't see would cause this error. You've added that it's an Inca file in brackets as if that's not likely to be important, but it might be critical that you need to read specifically an MDF generated by Inca - there is a [file exchange submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52952-mdf-import-tool-and-function-updated-for-mdf-file-format-from-inca-7-1-9) dedicated to that exact purpose which makes me suspect it's not trivial